# what are the know issues in Windows XP for WPF?

Tags: wpf

I am looking at the various issues that would come for running a WPF app on Win Xp machine. I know XP is out of date but specific requirement demands it.
Possible workarounds for WPF over Windows XP.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're limited on .Net framework version

Comment: What nkoniishvt said, and there were also some graphic performance and text rendering issues I think.

Comment: Theme is also different, so a lot of default styles for xaml controls will look different.